# Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked still occuring even after adding InstantTaskExecutorRule

Tags: android, junit5, android-livedata

I'm getting `getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked` exception. I 've added `InstantTaskExecutorRule` rule but still, it's not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's working after adding this class and adding the annotation on top of test class.

@ExtendWith(InstantExecutorExtension::class)

```
class InstantExecutorExtension : BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {

    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance()
            .setDelegate(object : TaskExecutor() {
                override fun executeOnDiskIO(runnable: Runnable) = runnable.run()

                override fun postToMainThread(runnable: Runnable) = runnable.run()

                override fun isMainThread(): Boolean = true
            })
    }

    override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().setDelegate(null)
    }
}
```